# iOS Parse PFQueryTableViewController pagination issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pagination, pfquery

I'm using `PFQueryTableViewController` in my project, and I just discovered a pretty annoying problem.

I'm using the pagination, everything works fine, but when the current user just finished loading/refreshing for the table(**not loading for next page**), suddenly another user makes a post(let's call it object0), then the pagination won't work as expected. For example, I have 100 objects on the Parse server, and the `objectsPerPage`  is set to 10. And this is what the table looks like after current user loading the table:

> object1
>
> object2
>
> object3
>
> ...
>
> object10
>
> load next page

Then suddenly another user makes a post "object0", and when the current user finishes loading next page, the table looks like this:

> object1
>
> object2
>
> ...
>
> object10
>
> object10
>
> object11
>
> ...
>
> object 19
>
> load next page

which gives me two "object10". And this is perfect reasonable because this is what Parse's logic for `loadNextPage` :

```
query.limit = self.objectsPerPage; //retrieve 10 objects per query
query.skip = page * self.objectsPerPage; //skip 10*current_page objects per query
```

As you can see, when another user makes a post(let's call it "object0"), there will be 101 objects on the server, but the table are still displaying from "object1" to "object10" coz it's not refreshed. And when current user is loading the 2nd page(this is not refreshing), the server's gonna skip the first 10 objects("object0" to "object 9", rather than 1 to 10), therefore the result for second page will be "object 10" to "object 19", thus, there will be two "object 10" in the table.

Is there a way to eliminate this issue?

And sorry for my poor english, if you are not sure what I meant to say, just comment below and I will explain further.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. Here is the approach:

- Create a new property called `lastObject`, which is the last object that the query returns.
- When the query has done executing without errors, update the `lastObject`.
- Create a new query, which queries the `self.parseClassName`, and then enumerate through the result, if the objectId of the `lastObject` is equal to an objectId in the result, then set the `query.skip = (index + 1)*page`. where `index` is the index of the object in the result array which matches the `lastObject`.
- After that, everytime we call the `loadNextPage`, the query should return the next 10 objects right after the `lastObject`.

It's a bit tricky, if anyone is facing the same problem, feel free to drop a message and I will expain my approach in detail. :)